# laravel4 doctrine not using apc cache

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, laravel-4, apc

My problem is basically that doctrine doesn't use the apc cached result when re-running the same query. Because of this i get long execution time. I didn't find a similar problem on the net.

**My environment:**

WAMP (32bit) with `PHP 5.4.16` on Windows7. 
MySQL database on remote database with a `87ms` average ping.
Laravel4 with laravel-doctrine package installed via composer:

```
doctrine/dbal - 2.4.x-dev
doctrine/orm  - 2.4.x-dev
```

**My problem:**

The cached doctrine query builder doesn't use the cached apc data.

Query:

```
    $query = Doctrine::createQueryBuilder();

    $query->select('e')->from("Persistent\Users\Experts\Expert", "e");

    $this->prepareSort($sort, $query);
    $query->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortVector);

    //prepare paginator
    $queryPaginator = new DoctrinePaginator($query);
    $this->total = $queryPaginator->count();

    return $queryPaginator  ->getQuery()
                            ->setResultCacheDriver(new ApcCache())
                            ->useResultCache(true, 300, 'expertsearch')
                            ->setFirstResult(0)
                            ->setMaxResults(20)
                            ->getResult();
```

Result:

The query takes about 17 seconds to complete because of distance between my machine and the database server.

Enabling caching as shown above doesn't affect the speed.

The APC use cache looks as follows:

```
DoctrineNamespaceCacheKey[] 1   584 2013/10/30 08:33:08 2013/10/30 08:33:08 2013/10/30 08:33:08 None    [Delete Now]
[expertsearch][1]   0   27880   2013/10/30 08:33:08 2013/10/30 08:33:08 2013/10/30 08:33:08 300 seconds [Delete Now]
[121cbb9b3c38e7d5a0c0e7b74c59e640][1]   0   3672    2013/10/30 08:33:08 2013/10/30 08:33:08 2013/10/30 08:33:08 None    [Delete Now]
```

Webgrind shows no change in the number of calls to PDO compared to when not using the cache in the query builder.

```
Function        Invocation Count    Total Self Cost     Total Inclusive Cost
php::PDOStatement->execute      183     15932   15932
php::PDO->query         7   588     588
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APC cache is used to store `OPCode` if you want to store queries you should use `Memcache`

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html#memcache

**Edit 1** :

As you asked me to develop my answer I'll do so.

How `PHP` works (simplified) ? `RE2C` will first do a Lexical analysies (for >=PHP5.3 and `Flex` for <=PHP5.2).

`Tokens` are generated.

Then, the Parser have to analyze the tokens. For example it looks if you have a "(" after a function (`T_FUNCTION, T_IF, T_OPEN`...) The parsers name is `Bison`.

Then, your code is compiled in table of `OPCode`.
For the end, there is an executer that will execute your code `PHP`.

So if you want, just to execute your code and not analyze and parse.. so you can use a `PHP accelerator` like `APC`. So, your `PHP` code will execute a lot faster but, the queries are executed every time you call your code. You're right, the documentation of Doctrine doesn't say it doesn't store the RESULT of queries but since it uses APC, it just stores THE QUERY.

`Memcache` is a Distributed Object Caching Memory System, it stores the result of a query. It has a distributed server.

I hope I was more clear in this response, sorry if my english is not very well...

Comment: The documentation url provided doesn't say `APC` doesn't store query results. In fact it even shows an example of how to use `APC`: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html#apc

Comment: Could you develop your answer a bit more?